# How does `diagnosticsStore` works in standalone service fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Trying to understand how `diagnosticsStore` works in service fabric. Inside config file I can see it requires SMB file to be provided but I don't see an option to specify username/password. How exactly individual hosts will authenticate to that share in stand alone cluster secured with X509 certificates which are in workgroup. Also what is `storeType` value is? Does it mean it's possible to use something other then SMB to store that information?

`"properties": {
        "diagnosticsStore": 
        {
            "metadata":  "Please replace the diagnostics file share with an actual file share accessible from all cluster machines. For example, \\\\machine1\\DiagnosticsStore.",
            "dataDeletionAgeInDays": "21",
            "storeType": "FileShare",
            "connectionstring": "\\\\machine1\\DiagnosticsStore"
        },`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to provide username\password in diagnosticStore.

The cluster's account will be used to access network share. Service fabric node works under Network Account by default, but you can change account for entire cluster (not recommended) or [change account for each service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-run-service-as-ad-user-or-group). This article for AD user, but local should also work by providing . (dot) as domain name. You will need to create same user with same password on all your workgroup joined servers (don't forget to give required permission for this account to make sure that service can do it job)

`storeType` can be `azureStorage` 
(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-manifest)

Comment: Local accounts does not seem to work `FabricDeployer
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryOperationException: Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest.`

Comment: @GregorySuvalian thanks for sharing, that was just a guess from me.

Answer (score 0):

From https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/64ba61a5-1b17-4387-a751-15aeb064d8c8/what-values-of-diagnosticsstore-in-configuration-file-can-be

> Each machine account will have to be ACLed to the file share for this to work.

Not directly answering your question, but Azure is a valid option, one I've tested and am moving ours toward:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-manifest#diagnostics

```
"diagnosticsStore": {
    "metadata":  "I recommend one Storage Account per cluster.",
    "dataDeletionAgeInDays": "21",
    "storeType": "AzureStorage",
    "IsEncrypted": "false",
    "connectionstring": "xstore:DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[AzureAccountName];AccountKey=[AzureAccountKey]"
}
```